# MPAndroidChart keeps throwing null error

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm just trying this library out to see if it fits my needs and so far I have not been able to get it to work. Here is the code

```
package com.example.user.bottomnavigationbar;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    PieChart pc;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    return true;

//                case R.id.navigation_overview:
//                    Intent intentOverview = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity_test.class);
//                    intentOverview.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                    MainActivity.this.finish();
//                    startActivity(intentOverview);
//                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_expenses:

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_reminder:

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_income:

                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_login:
                    Intent intentLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intentLogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    startActivity(intentLogin);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        pc = findViewById(R.id.chart);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        ArrayList <PieEntry> pieData = new ArrayList<>();
        pieData.add(new PieEntry(10));
        pieData.add(new PieEntry(20));
        pieData.add(new PieEntry(30));
        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieData, "Survey Results");
        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        pc.setData(data);
    }


    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Closing Activity")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.bottomnavigationbar, PID: 4172
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.bottomnavigationbar/com.example.user.bottomnavigationbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart.setData(com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart.setData(com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.user.bottomnavigationbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I've searched for a bit and all I've found was that for others, they did not initialize the object hence it throws this error. Now someone did mention that it is possible to create the chart in code and then add it to the activity as the documentation's Getting Started page suggests but I have been unable to get it working. So what gives?

P.S Left in the code for navigation as I'm not sure if it might be the cause of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are first finding the view and then providing the content view to your activity  replace with this code

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            pc = findViewById(R.id.chart);
            BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
            navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
            ArrayList <PieEntry> pieData = new ArrayList<>();
            pieData.add(new PieEntry(10));
            pieData.add(new PieEntry(20));
            pieData.add(new PieEntry(30));
            PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieData, "Survey Results");
            PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
            pc.setData(data);
        }
```

Comment: Yup it works, silly me, didn't realise I placed it before I set the content view. Thanks!